# Automatically resolving disambiguation pages

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

## The problem

I'm using the Wikipedia API to get page HTML which I parse. I use queries like [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?redirects=1&section=0&prop=text&action=parse&page=Apple+Computer) to get the HTML for the first section of a page.

The MediaWiki API provides a handy parameter, `redirects`, which will cause the API to automatically follow pages that redirect other pages. For example, if I search for 'Cats' with [`https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?page=Cats&redirects`](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?page=Cats&redirects), I will be shown the results for `Cat` because `Cats` redirects to `Cat`.

I'd like a similar function for [disambiguation pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Disambiguation) such as [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web), by which if I arrive at a disambiguation page, I am automatically redirected to the first link. For example, if I make a request to a page like [Mercury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury), I'd automatically be redirected to [Mercury (element)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_(element)), as it is the first link listed in the page.

The Python HTML parser `BeautifulSoup` is fairly slow on large documents. By only requesting the first section of articles (that's all I need for my use), using `section=0`, I can parse it quickly. This is perfect for most articles. But for disambiguation pages, the first section does *not* include any of the links to specific pages, making it a poor solution. But if I request *more* than the first section, the HTML loading slows down, which is unnecessary for most articles. See [this query](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=Web&prop=text&section=0) for an example of a disambiguation page in which links are not included in the first section.

## What I have so far

As of right now, I've gotten as far as detecting when a disambiguation page is reached. I use code like

```
bs4.BeautifulSoup(page_html).find("p", recursive=false).get_text().endswith(("refer to:", "refers to:"))
```

I also spent a while trying to write code that automatically followed a link, before I realized that the links were not included in

## My constraints

I'd prefer to keep the number of requests made to a minimum. I also need to be parsing as *little HTML as possible*, because speed is essential for my application.

## Possible solutions (which I need help executing)

I could envision several solutions to this problem:

1. A way within the MediaWiki API to automatically follow the first link from disambiguation pages
2. A method within the Mediawiki API that allows it to return different amounts of HTML content based on a condition (like presence of a disambiguation template)
3. A way to dramatically improve the speed of `bs4` so that it doesn't matter if I end up having to parse the entire page HTML

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to download the wikipedia database and work on it locally? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download

Comment: I'm working on a 20GB web server, so no :P

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using [Pywikibot](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot) or at least API calls? You can just use `page.isDisambig()` with pywikibot (no need to parse HTML) and you can also simply request the internal links (`action=query&prop=links`)... There is almost never a need to scrape the HTML content of MediaWiki pages...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker My use involves extracting all the links from the first paragraph of an article. For more info, look at [the README on my project](https://github.com/The-Penultimate-Defenestrator/wikipedia-map/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker To clarify, I'm not scraping pages (that's against [this policy](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Bot_policy#Unacceptable_usage), but I'm parsing HTML returned from API requests.

Comment: There are [about 270,000 disambiguation pages in total](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:All_disambiguation_pages), caching *all* of them would take about 4G of space (using a title length of 16 characters, it may be more as I don't know what the avg. title length), so that sounds do-able; that way you only have to parse it once... As a general remark about the project: I'm not sure if following the first link from a disambiguation page is a good strategy, by the way − I suspect you will get some very strange results as the meaning of a a disambiguation page is, well, ambiguous :-) ...

Comment: ... That's why there is no automatic redirect feature. Usually they're linked to by careless editors who don't bother to check what they're linking to and just slapping `[[..]]` tags around everything they see (ideally, disambiguation pages should never be linked to). I'm not sure if the first link is even what is intended *more often* than any of the other links...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Thanks for the lengthy reply. I think 4GB of space is more than I want to spend, so I'm gonna see if I can find an alternate solution. As far as your other point, as far as I've seen, the first link is *usually* more relevant than the others, even if it's not the most relevant. If no better responses come in, I'll ask you to post that as an answer and accept it. Thanks ;)

Comment: 4GB is more than I want to spend mostly because I've only got one web server for all my projects. I want to have as much space as possible for other things, and keep stuff pretty small.

Comment: HTML parsing is never a good idea. Use [Wikidata](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q48397), that pageprops API (disambiguation pages have a `disambiguation` property), [mwparserfromhell](https://mwparserfromhell.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tgr and everybody said, no, such a feature doesn't exist because it doesn't make sense. The first link in a disambiguation page doesn't have any special status or meaning.

As for the existing API, see https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Disambiguator#API_usage

By the way, the "bot policy" you linked does not really apply to crawlers/scraper; the only relevant policy/guideline is the [User-Agent policy](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/User-Agent_policy).